# GoogleAuthenticator PAM Module Permissions Issue -- VPN with MFA in AWS EC2 running CentOS

Tags: centos, permissions, vpn, pam, selinux

#### Full Disclosure:

> I am writing this question to then answer it myself. I searched the internet for a full day at work and was not able to find a solution that worked for me. I even compiled my own GoogleAuthenticator PAM module to add more logging. Not even running `strace` on the OpenVPN process and its children led me to a solution.

## Use Case

- Launch VPN using OpenVPN in an EC2
- Use PAM GoogleAuthenticator Module
- OS: CentOS

## Setup

- login to the EC2
- create a client
- add MFA token to user (client) using the provided token generator while also saving this token to the proper location for the PAM module to detect it

  - create the `<user>.ovpn` file for this user

The below script will create a Linux user, and then create an MFA secret saved to the location specified in the PAM config, note the permissions `600`, `MFA_USER` is a pre-created user that I created named `gauth`

```bsh
function generate_mfa() {
  user_id=$1

  if [ "$user_id" == "" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: No user id provided to generate MFA token" >&2
    exit 1
  fi

  echo "INFO: Creating user ${user_id}" >&2
  useradd -s /bin/nologin "$user_id"

  echo "> Please provide a password for the user" >&2
  passwd "$user_id"

  echo "INFO: Generating MFA Token" >&2
  google-authenticator -t -d -r3 -R30 -f -l "${MFA_LABEL}" -s "${MFA_DIR}/${user_id}"
  chown "${MFA_USER}:${MFA_USER}" "$MFA_DIR/${user_id}"
  chmod 600 "${MFA_DIR}/${user_id}"
}
```

PAM Config for OpenVPN

```
auth        required    /usr/lib64/security/pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/etc/openvpn/google-authenticator/${USER} user=gauth  forward_pass
auth        include     system-auth    use_first_pass
account     include     system-auth    use_first_pass
password    include     system-auth    use_first_pass
session     include     system-auth    use_first_pass
auth        required    pam_deny.so
```

## Issue

- Using Tunnelblick configured with my `client.ovpn`, I am then prompted to log in with my username and password.

  - The format of password is inline: `<password><MFA_TOKEN>`, this is stripped out with the `forward_pass` directive
- I enter in my proper credentials and am always met with unauthorized

## Logs

- To check out my issue I logged onto the VPN instance via ssh and inspected my PAM/auth logs `tail /var/log/secure`

```
Sep 10 22:33:43 ip-OMITTED openvpn(pam_google_authenticator)[12862]: Accepted google_authenticator for ryan
Sep 10 22:33:43 ip-OMITTED openvpn(pam_google_authenticator)[12862]: Failed to update secret file "/etc/openvpn/google-authenticator/ryan": Permission denied
```

### Aha! "Permission Denied"

So then check my permissions:

```
[root@ip-OMITTED centos]# ls -lah /etc/openvpn/google-authenticator/
drwxr-xr-x. gauth gauth .
drwxr-xr-x. root  root  ..
-rw-------. gauth gauth ryan
```

- Hmm, these permissions `600` seem right. The directories are executable and I am using the `gauth` user in my PAM config.

### What on earth could be wrong with my configuration?

- the `gauth` user exists `:check:`
- the permissions are right `:check:`

Answer (score 2):

### THE AHA MOMENT

> what are those `.`'s at the end of my permissions listing?

```
[root@ip-OMITTED centos]# ls -lah /etc/openvpn/google-authenticator/
drwxr-xr-x. gauth gauth .
drwxr-xr-x. root  root  ..
-rw-------. gauth gauth ryan
```

`...Searchin' the web...`

- So apparently there's this thing called [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) (security enhanced linux)

*That* is what those dots were at the end of the file permissions when running `ls -lah`, it indicated that special contexts/ACL stuff existed for the file.

- See: [SELinux Docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files)
- So, to see the contexts:  `ls -Z`

#### Before one login

The file context was `unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0`

```
[root@ip-OMITTED centos]# ls -lahZ /etc/openvpn/google-authenticator/
drwxr-xr-x. gauth gauth unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. root  root  system_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 ..
-rw-------. gauth gauth unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 ryan
```

- Then I temporarily disabled selinux with `setenforce 0`

#### After one login

*The file was able to be written to and the context was coerced to* `system_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_rw_t:s0`

```
[root@ip-OMITTED centos]# ls -lahZ /etc/openvpn/google-authenticator/
drwxr-xr-x. gauth gauth unconfined_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. root  root  system_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_t:s0 ..
-r--------. gauth gauth system_u:object_r:openvpn_etc_rw_t:s0 ryan
```

- reenable SELinux: `setenforce 1`
- still able to log in. :)

### Commands to run to fix a file with SELinux turned on:

`semanage fcontext -a -t openvpn_etc_rw_t  "${MFA_DIR}/${user}"`
  `restorecon  "${MFA_DIR}/${user}"`

- This allows the `rw` bits!